# Change php include when clicking on button (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, include

I have a list of buttons. Whenever I press button 1, it is supposed to change the currently opened php include into another php include. I did it this way:

```
$('.allbuttons #button1').click(function() {
    $('.textDiv').hide().show('<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/link1.php'); ?>')
});
```

And then if you click on button 2, it should change again:

```
$('.allbuttons #button2').click(function() {
    $('.textDiv').hide().show('<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/link2.php'); ?>')
});
```

The includes are filled with a div classed textDiv a h2 heading and some p text.

It doesn't seem to work, as you probably guessed :)

Edit: As people commented, I can't do this. Are there any other way I can change the header and paragraph?

Edit again: More comments! Yay! I thought about changing it like this, then:

```
$('.allbuttons #button2').click(function() {
    var h1 = 'header for link 1';
    var p1 = 'paragraph for link 1';
    $('.textDiv').html('<h1>' + h1 + '</h1> NEW LINE (how?) <p>' + p1 + '</p>')
});
```

Comment: My friend, PHP  is executed on the server and JavaScript is executed on a browser. What you are trying to do is execute php on browser which is impossible. Are you trying to load the content of the URL into a div?

Comment: There are many tutorials on how works communication between server and client, you should read some of that. And search for AJAX to call script server side

Answer (score 0):

There is no way it's going to work. PhP is interpreted on the server, prior to the javascript code running on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change an include. That's not an option.

It seems that you want to use AJAX.
You could load the content of the include in any element of the site using [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

For example. To load `link1.php` in the element `#links`, we could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.allbuttons #button1').click(function() {
         $('#links').load("http://"+ document.domain + "/includes/link1.php");
    });

    $('.allbuttons #button2').click(function() {
        $('#links').load("http://"+ document.domain + "/includes/link2.php");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible. PHP runs on the server and Jquery runs on your browser.

May be you want to change the content of a div or something

for that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.allbuttons #button2').click(function() {
         $("textdiv").html("<iframe src='http://yoururlhere.com'></iframe>")
     });   
});
```

Where the iframe source can be the url for the second link you want to show.

Comment: yeah you can do all that.... Put the new html code you want to show in that place 
$("textdiv").html("<h1>Paste your html here</h1>")